# What does the soldier say in Red Corner?

Tags: dialogue, translation, red-corner

In a pivotal scene in the 1997 movie *Red Corner*, a corrupt soldier realizes that his boss is no longer going to shield his involvement in a murder.  [He shouts "Da Gwar!"](https://youtu.be/nwv42Bs11RY) in outrage plus several other aggrieved syllables, presumably in Mandarin.  I let Google Translate have a try at it, but the app failed to translate the exclamation into English.

I've long wondered exactly what he said; can anyone provide a translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely tranlated word for "Da Gwar" is  actually "大官(Da guar)“ [REF:scripts](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/r/red-corner-script-transcript-gere.html). In practice , there are two possibilities.

1. First , it  can translate literally as "big officer"(大 for big, 官 for officer) and that usage matches the "big short" quoted in the movie.
2. Secondly, it can also use as a common nickname  between friends (both meanings could co-exist since it's possible to use a mocking title to a nickname or parental expectation calling for children) Furthermore.It's rare to call someone "Big officer" directly in conversation,the more common title used should be something else like "Leader(领导 or supervisor/manager)"

Comment: Can you help with the shouts that come after Da Guar?  The link in the question goes to a video of the scene so that you can hear it.

Comment: The shout after "Da Guar" isn't very clear. It doesn't sound as proper Mandarin (especially with emotion to blame the "Da Guar"). My best guess would be  like "你連羊也不如(You're worse than a sheep?)“ . It's a strange sentence . However ,it means to blame how lousy "Da Guar"  did after murder and all will be exposed now.